# Regenerate session id problems to expect

Tags: php, session-state

Im reading [session_regenerate_id()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id) and also the warning. Unfortunately it is not very clear on the workings and user experience.

What is against regenerating the session id and why is this specific a problem for mobile applications?

Comment: Why do you want to use `session_regenerate_id()`?

Comment: The warning doesn't say anything about mobile applications. It says it doesn't work well with unstable network connections - which may include poor WiFi networks or mobile data signals. That has nothing to do with mobile apps themselves directly.  But yeah, are you thinking of using this function, and if so, why? It's very rarely necessary.

Comment: We need this for an application that stays connected for a long time and we are wary of the fact that if a session_id is leaked it might allow session spoofing